# An almost periodic point must be a unifomly recurrent point?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

$(X,G)$ is a topological semi-group action, $G$ is a  topological (abelian) semigroup, and $X$ is a Hausdorff space.

$x\in X$ is called almost periodic of $(X,G)$, if for any neibourhood $U$ of $x$, $\{g\in G: gx\in U\}$ is syndetic.

$x\in X$ is called uniformly recurrent of $(X,G)$, if for any neibourhood $U$ of $x$, there exist a compact subset $K$ of $G$, such that for any $g\in G$, we can find a $k\in K$ satisfying $gkx\in U$.

$S$ is called a syndetic subset of a topologcal semigroup $G$, if we can find a compact subset of $G$, such that for any $g\in G$, there exist an $s\in S$, and a $k\in K$ satisfying $g=sk$.

My question is: if $x$ is almost periodic, then $x$ must be unifomly recurrent?

Comment: This is not a research related question, you should post it in MSE.

Comment: @Asaf Really? Maybe it is so difficult for me to think out. Please help me.